# How to install Canon PIXMA G2010 on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner, canon

I followed the instructions at seegatesite.com/driver-printer-canon-pixma-g2010-ubuntu/, but when I try to add the printer at Settings/Printers it says it needs drivers. Is there a better tutorial? Is there an easier method? Google has not been my friend in this effort. This is an installation of 20.10 on a 64GB USB stick, and I am not averse to reformatting the stick and starting over, but I need a printer. Actually I need the Canon Scangear, too. This is a dealbreaker. If I can't install a scanner and printer, I can't use Ubuntu. I could swear I got a printer installed on a version of Ubuntu several years ago, but don't remember anything about how I did it.

Comment: Are you running from the live media on the USB drive?

Comment: No, I have Ubuntu 20.10 installed on a 64GB USB stick and boot up from that. It's the only way to install programs I want to try out.

Comment: You made a persistent live media?

Comment: No. I did that once several years ago but for some reason found it unsatisfactory. Don't remember now. No, I just do a full installation of Ubuntu on a 64GB USB stick. I think it's /dev/sdc5. Works fine with USB 3.0. I think it was a little jerky on USB 2.0. It's one of the options in the install program, so I suspect other people are doing it as well. Theoretically, I could take the USB stick to any desktop that will boot from USB and have my home installation right there, with the ability to access files on the native hard drive.

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer at a question about a different Canon printer at AskUbuntu. Sorry, I didn't think to write down the name of the person who gave the answer so I can credit him. Run the command

```
sudo apt install printer-driver-gutenprint
```

Comment: Worked at 22.04!, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It can be installed by this:

https://youtu.be/Ql8RQUgWe8A

Generic text-only drivers are usually used for printing basic text documents without any formatting, images or graphics. Such drivers may not support color printing, and if they do, they may not offer the full range of color options available with the printer's original driver.